# SQL - Displaying data that reoccurs the most times

Tags: sql, database, select

I have a problem with displaying data that reoccurs the most amount of times in a table. 
For example, I have tables called JOB, TASK, and TASK_TYPE.

JOB contains job_id and job_price, and lists jobs. Each job contains several tasks

TASK contains job_id and task_id, E.g.

```
****job_id**        **task_id**
J01                     T01
J01                     T03
J02                     T01
J02                     T02
J02                     T03
J03                     T01
J04                     T01
```

TASK_TYPE contains task_id and task_description. It lists different tasks available for clients. E.g.

```
**task_id**    **task_description**
T01                   shopping
T02                   dog walking
T03                   car wash
```

I would like to display which task type has been used the most, and the jobs it has been used for, which in this case would be T01. So far I've got this code, but I have no idea how to display only the most reoccurring tasks.

```
SELECT j.job_id, t.task_id, tt.type
    FROM job j
        JOIN task t ON j.job_id = t.job_id
            JOIN task_type tt ON t.task_id = tt.task_id GROUP BY tt.type, t.task_id, j.job_id ORDER BY type;
```

Comment: Which dbms??????????  It's useless if someone post answer to Oracle, but you use MySQL.

Comment: Some answer below are for MySQL, some for SQL Server.  That's what happen if you don't tag properly!!!

Answer (score 1):

Using `TOP 1` logic as @LONG mentioned:

```
SELECT A.TASK_ID, A.JOB_ID, B.TASK_DESCRIPTION
FROM
(SELECT TASK_ID, JOB_ID
FROM TASK
WHERE TASK_ID IN (SELECT TOP 1 TASK_ID FROM TASK GROUP BY TASK_ID ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC)) A
INNER JOIN
TASK_TYPE B
ON A.TASK_ID = B.TASK_ID;
```

In case there are more than one `TASK_ID`s with the same highest occurrence frequency, try this:

```
SELECT B.JOB_ID, Z.TASK_ID, C.TASK_DESCRIPTION
(SELECT A.TASK_ID, DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY A.FREQ DESC) AS MOST_FREQ
FROM
    (SELECT TASK_ID, COUNT(*) AS FREQ FROM TASK GROUP BY TASK_ID) A
) Z
INNER JOIN
TASK B
ON Z.TASK_ID = B.TASK_ID AND Z.MOST_FREQ = 1
INNER JOIN
TASK_TYPE C
ON B.TASK_ID = C.TASK_ID;
```

This will give you results in separate rows though. That is what you seem to require based on the query you have tried in your post :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the below query, you can ignore the CTEs ahead, just for sample data.

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
select 'J01' as job_id,            'T01' as task_id
union all select 'J01',                    'T03'
union all select 'J02' ,                    'T01'
union all select 'J02' ,                    'T02'
union all select 'J02' ,                    'T03'
union all select 'J03'  ,                   'T01'
union all select 'J04' ,                    'T01'
),

TASK_TYPE
AS
(
SELECT 'T01' as task_id, 'shopping' as task_description
UNION ALL SELECT 'T02' , 'dog walking'
UNION ALL SELECT 'T03' , 'car wash'
)

SELECT TOP 1 B.TASK_ID,C.task_description,STUFF((SELECT ',' + A.job_id FROM CTE as A where A.task_id = B.task_id FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') as Related_Job
FROM CTE as B
INNER JOIN TASK_TYPE as C
ON C.task_id = B.task_id
GROUP BY B.TASK_ID,C.task_description
ORDER by COUNT(*) DESC
```

OUTPUT:

```
TASK_ID    task_description           Related_Job
T01        shopping                   J01,J02,J03,J04
```

Comment: Damn, that just blew my mind :D I'm quite new to databases and to be honest I understand 10% of your answer haha. Thank you for help though :)

Comment: nah, I learned from writing the answer :) hopefully that works for you, and the actual query starts from that `SELECT TOP1..`, short ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite new to SQL myself therefore I'm sorry for my messy query, but it works for me in MySQL.

```
SELECT j.job_id, t.task_id, tt.task_description 
FROM job j 
JOIN task t ON j.job_id = t.job_id 
JOIN task_type tt ON t.task_id = tt.task_id 
where t.task_id = (
select tx.task_id 
from (SELECT t.task_id, count(t.task_id) as accurance FROM job j JOIN task t ON j.job_id = t.job_id JOIN task_type tt ON t.task_id = tt.task_id group by t.task_id limit 1) as tx) 
GROUP BY tt.task_description, t.task_id, j.job_id order by task_description;
```

I hope this is easy to understand for you since we are both new to databases.
If you have any questions feel free to ask.

Here is my output:

```
+--------+---------+------------------+
| job_id | task_id | task_description |
+--------+---------+------------------+
| J01    | T01     | shopping         |
| J02    | T01     | shopping         |
| J03    | T01     | shopping         |
| J04    | T01     | shopping         |
+--------+---------+------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses the WITH syntax (tested with Oracle 11g R2) to organize sub queries to make query easy to read. It also will handle the case where a task_id count is tied (in provided example T03 and T01 are tied). Hope this is useful to you!

#### Query

```
-- set up example tables
WITH TASK AS (
  SELECT 'J01' AS job_id, 'T01' AS task_id FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'J01' AS job_id, 'T03' AS task_id FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'J02' AS job_id, 'T03' AS task_id FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'J02' AS job_id, 'T02' AS task_id FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'J02' AS job_id, 'T03' AS task_id FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'J03' AS job_id, 'T01' AS task_id FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'J04' AS job_id, 'T01' AS task_id FROM dual),
TASK_TYPE AS (
  SELECT 'T01' AS task_id, 'shopping' AS task_description FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'T02' AS task_id, 'dog walking' AS task_description FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'T03' AS task_id, 'car wash' AS task_description FROM dual),
-- rank order by task_id count
TASK_RANK AS (
  SELECT task_id, COUNT(task_id) AS task_counts
  FROM TASK
  GROUP BY task_id),
-- get name of most frequent tasks (will handle tie)
TOP_TASK AS (
  SELECT task_id 
  FROM TASK_RANK
  WHERE task_counts IN (SELECT MAX(task_counts) FROM TASK_RANK))

-- simple query to get tasks
SELECT T.task_id, T.job_id, TT.task_description
FROM TASK T
INNER JOIN TASK_TYPE TT
ON T.task_id = TT.task_id
WHERE T.task_id IN (SELECT task_id FROM TOP_TASK)
ORDER BY task_id
```

#### Output

```
| TASK_ID | JOB_ID | TASK_DESCRIPTION |
|---------|--------|------------------|
|     T01 |    J04 |         shopping |
|     T01 |    J03 |         shopping |
|     T01 |    J01 |         shopping |
|     T03 |    J02 |         car wash |
|     T03 |    J02 |         car wash |
|     T03 |    J01 |         car wash |
```